# Python: how to group similar lists together in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, group-by

I have a list of lists in python. I want to group similar lists together. That is, if first three elements of each list are the same then those three lists should go in one group. For eg

```
[["a", "b", "c", 1, 2],

["d", "f", "g", 8, 9],

["a", "b", "c", 3, 4],

["d","f", "g", 3, 4],

["a", "b", "c", 5, 6]]
```

I want this to look like

```
[[["a", "b", "c", 1, 2],

["a", "b", "c", 5, 6],

["a", "b", "c", 3, 4]],

[["d","f", "g", 3, 4],

["d", "f", "g", 8, 9]]]
```

I could do this by running an iterator and manually comparing each element of two consecutive lists and then based on the no of elements within those lists that were same I can decide to group them together. But i was just wondering if there is any other way or a pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) :

```
>>> A=[["a", "b", "c", 1, 2],
...    ["d", "f", "g", 8, 9],
...    ["a", "b", "c", 3, 4],
...    ["d","f", "g", 3, 4],
...    ["a", "b", "c", 5, 6]]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(A),itemgetter(0,1,2)]
[[['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2], ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 5, 6]], [['d', 'f', 'g', 3, 4], ['d', 'f', 'g', 8, 9]]]
```

Comment: itemgetter would be a nicer approach `[list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(A),itemgetter(0,1,2))]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah thanks I was thinking about that!

Comment: You forget to close the groupby( parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to sort, you can group in a dict using a tuple of the first three elements from each list as the key:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l=[    
  ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2],    
  ["d", "f", "g", 8, 9],    
  ["a", "b", "c", 3, 4],    
  ["d","f", "g", 3, 4],
  ["a", "b", "c", 5, 6]    
]

od = OrderedDict()
for sub in l:
    k = tuple(sub[:3])
    od.setdefault(k,[]).append(sub)
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(od.values())
[[['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2], ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 5, 6]],
[['d', 'f', 'g', 8, 9], ['d', 'f', 'g', 3, 4]]]
```

Which is `O(n)` as opposed to `O(n log n)`.

If you don't care about order use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict


od = defaultdict(list)
for sub in l:
    a, b, c, *_ = sub # python3
    k = a,b,c
    od[k].append(sub)

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(list(od.values()))
[[['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2], ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 5, 6]],
 [['d', 'f', 'g', 8, 9], ['d', 'f', 'g', 3, 4]]]
```

Comment: As `groupby` returns a generators its very efficient at memory perspective and yours is more efficient at time ;) so +1!

Comment: @Kasra,  I think you will find that sorted stores a new list of all the elements in memory so dict still wins   you can also iterate over  itervalues in python2 or values in python3 ;)

Comment: No its the Only use of mem but you use in each iteration `tuple(sub[:3])` and the dict

Comment: @Kasra, that is only three elements so not much overhead unless the list is huge, also if you want to take advantage of the iterator you would need to use a for loop with groupby. I also only store the same amount of data as sorted does is my list of values.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `sorted` followed by `groupby` is doubly inefficient versus this O(n) solution.