# How to split a list into a list of sublists that contain duplicate values in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, group-by

I have a list of lists of information about tides at certain times each day. It looks kinda like this:

```
tideData = [
['Thursday 4 January',11.58,0.38],
['Thursday 4 January',16.95,0.73],
['Friday 5 January',6.48,0.83],
['Friday 5 January',12.42,0.33],
['Saturday 6 January',0.5,0.02],
['Saturday 6 January',7.18,0.85],
...
['Friday 2 February',23.52,0.04]
]
```

I would like to split this list into sublists containing the same dates. In the case above, the list would become:

```
tideData = [
[['Thursday 4 January',11.58,0.38],
['Thursday 4 January',16.95,0.73]],
[['Friday 5 January',6.48,0.83],
['Friday 5 January',12.42,0.33],
['Friday 5 January',17.92,0.75]],
[['Saturday 6 January',0.5,0.02],
['Saturday 6 January',7.18,0.85]],
...
['Friday 2 February',23.52,0.04]]
]
```

Now, this wouldn't be a problem if there was an equal number of each date. However, the dates sometimes appear twice and sometimes appear three times. As such, I'd like to be able to sort them into sublists based on repeat dates. How would I go about this?

Comment: Have you tried something? Did you write a piece of algorithm? Did you write a piece of python? If yes, what blocks you? If no, do it :) Show that you tried, and we'll help you, it seems like basic python to me.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Python: how to group similar lists together in a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987825/python-how-to-group-similar-lists-together-in-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for an O(n) solution.

In Python 3.7, you will have the added benefit that the order of values will match the order in the input. This works in Python 3.6, but is considered an implementation detail.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in tideData:
    d[item[0]].append(item)
    
res = list(d.values())
```

Result:

```
[[['Thursday 4 January', 11.58, 0.38], ['Thursday 4 January', 16.95, 0.73]],
 [['Friday 5 January', 6.48, 0.83], ['Friday 5 January', 12.42, 0.33]],
 [['Saturday 6 January', 0.5, 0.02], ['Saturday 6 January', 7.18, 0.85]],
 [['Friday 2 February', 23.52, 0.04]]]
```

For those interested in performance difference between O(n) and O(n log n) solutions:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

tideData = [
['Thursday 4 January',11.58,0.38],
['Thursday 4 January',16.95,0.73],
['Friday 5 January',6.48,0.83],
['Friday 5 January',12.42,0.33],
['Saturday 6 January',0.5,0.02],
['Saturday 6 January',7.18,0.85],
['Friday 2 February',23.52,0.04]
]

tideData = tideData * 10000

def jp(tideData):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for item in tideData:
        d[item[0]].append(item)
    return list(d.values())

def grp(tideData):
    grouper = groupby(sorted(tideData, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))
    return [list(g) for _, g in grouper]

%timeit jp(tideData)   # 5.63 ms per loop
%timeit grp(tideData)  # 9.87 ms per loop
```

Comment: "In Python 3.6, you have the added benefit that the order of values will match the order in the input." The Python docs say that this should not be relied on as it is an implementation detail and may not hold true forever.

Comment: @DeepSpace, Guido has confirmed 3.7 will maintain order! So your quote may be overridden.

Comment: The `sort+groupby` approach incurs a `n log(n)` cost because of the sort, not because of the groupby. But you actually forgot to sort in the code.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use `groupby` from the `itertools` package

```
from itertools import groupby

tideData = [
['Thursday 4 January',11.58,0.38],
['Thursday 4 January',16.95,0.73],
['Friday 5 January',6.48,0.83],
['Friday 5 January',12.42,0.33],
['Saturday 6 January',0.5,0.02],
['Saturday 6 January',7.18,0.85],
['Friday 2 February',23.52,0.04]
]
```

If you data is not sorted, you can use:

```
tideData = sorted(tideData, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

before using the following:

```
[list(g) for _,g in groupby(tideData, key=lambda x: x[0])]
# returns:
[[['Thursday 4 January', 11.58, 0.38], ['Thursday 4 January', 16.95, 0.73]],
 [['Friday 5 January', 6.48, 0.83], ['Friday 5 January', 12.42, 0.33]],
 [['Saturday 6 January', 0.5, 0.02], ['Saturday 6 January', 7.18, 0.85]],
 [['Friday 2 February', 23.52, 0.04]]]
```

Comment: This is my favored approach as it is guaranteed to be stable **(as long as** `tideData` **is already sorted by date)**

Comment: Note that the optional argument `key=lambda x: x[0]` in `tideData = sorted(tideData, key=lambda x: x[0])` is only needed if you want to preserve the order of the data for each day. Otherwise, you can just sort without providing a key. Tuples are sorted in lexicographical order, which gives the highest priority to `x[0]` already.

Comment: @DeepSpace Also note that python sort is a stable sort.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple approach without any import :

```
groub_by={}
for i,j in enumerate(tideData):
    if j[0] not in groub_by:
        groub_by[j[0]]=[j]
    else:
        groub_by[j[0]].append(j)
print(groub_by.values())
```

output:

```
[[['Thursday 4 January', 11.58, 0.38], ['Thursday 4 January', 16.95, 0.73]], [['Saturday 6 January', 0.5, 0.02], ['Saturday 6 January', 7.18, 0.85]], [['Friday 5 January', 6.48, 0.83], ['Friday 5 January', 12.42, 0.33]], [['Friday 2 February', 23.52, 0.04]]]
```